# Is there a way to change an MP3 (or other format's) title mid-file?

Tags: mp3, tagging

I have my own python-based MP3 file organisation, and one of the things I have issues with is concept albums, where a single (long) track has multiple sub parts. There seem to be 2 options:

1. Have a single mp3 (/wma/ogg/etc) file, and lose the title info about the sub-parts
2. Have separate files for each part, which aren't really whole pieces and don't make sense independently.

Is there a way I can embed metadata in the file so that players will display the current part's title, changing it mid file at the appropriate points?

Answer (score 1):

### For MP3

For both ID3v2.3 and v2.4 there was an addition for exactly this case:

> **ID3 Chapter Frame Addendum**
>
> ID3 Chapter (CHAP) and Table of Contents (CTOC) frames were developed in response to the growth in audio files containing more than one distinct audio program. Podcasts are an example of a single audio file which may contain multiple tracks, stories or other distinct audio entries. The addition of the CHAP and CTOC frames to an ID3 tag will provide compatible players with index information into the audio file.
>
> Version 1.0 of the Chapter Frame Addendum was released on December 2, 2005. CTOC & CHAP frames are compatible with ID3v2.3 and ID3v2.4 tags.
>
> [ID3v2 Chapter Frame Addendum v1.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20180402044145/http://id3.org/id3v2-chapters-1.0)

Which means the ID3v2 tag contains (in your case) 2 `CHAP` frames and each one embeds a `TIT2` frame:

> [image: example of a "CHAP" frame containing two embedded sub-frames]

However, I have no clue

- which tagging program supports creating ID3v2 tags with these frames, and
- which player program being able to read ID3v2 tags supports it to this extent.

Chances are this only exists on paper without gaining much attention from the world. But, as you see, it's totally possible.

### For MP3, alternative

You can indirectly achieve this with [synchronized lyrics: the `SYLT` frame](https://web.archive.org/web/20200413172744/https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Synchronised_lyrics.2Ftext) should be better supported by players - the documentation even thought of this with a distinctive *Content type* value:

> `$03` is movement/part name (e.g. "Adagio")

### For OGG/OGA

The native metadata format is [VorbisComment](https://wiki.xiph.org/VorbisComment) - for that there's also a [Chapter Extension proposal](https://wiki.xiph.org/Chapter_Extension) which aims at a pretty simple syntax. Since VorbisComment itself is only text you can achieve this easily yourself (to see which player can understand it):

> An example chapter file with two sequential chapters:
>
> ```
> CHAPTER001=00:00:00.000
> CHAPTER001NAME=Chapter 1
> CHAPTER002=00:05:00.000
> CHAPTER002NAME=Chapter 2
> ```

### For WMA/ASF

Maybe for this the [Marker object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mf-pd-asf-marker-attribute) is useful (GUID `{F487CD01-A951-11CF-8EE6-00C00C205365}`). Good luck on finding a program being able to precisely set these for you and players which care for this metadata at all. Windows Media is too propritary and in terms of metadata rather clumsy - avoid it.